# AutoComplete does not kick in when first character is 0

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, autocomplete

Does anyone know why my AutoComplete is not working when the first character I type is 0 (zero)? For debugging purposes I setup my AC to just tell me a row was found or not, and it seems that for any character I type as the first character it tells me so, except 0. I have to type in a second character after 0 for it to kick in and start working. It's as if the `minLength` attribute is `2` when the first char is 0. Has anyone run into or heard of this and know how to fix it? Here is my code:

```
//AutoComplete code in question
$(function() {
    var itemcode_ac = {
        source: "/webservices/whs_bincodeAC.php",
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#txtBin').val(ui.item.value);
            getWhsInfo();
        },
        minLength: 1
    }
    $('#txtBin').autocomplete(itemcode_ac);
});
```

whs_bincodeAC.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["term"]) && !empty($_GET["term"])) {
    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/to/dbConnect.php';
    $term = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_GET["term"]));
    //wildcard appended here for parameterized query (MySqli)
    $term .= "%";

    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT BinCode, ItemCode, ItemName, WhsCode, DataAsOfDate FROM whse_tbl 
        WHERE BinCode LIKE '$term' or ItemCode LIKE '$term' ORDER BY BinCode LIMIT 0, 10";
    $res = mysql_query($query);

    //This is the debug code I described above
    /*if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
        echo json_encode(array(array('value' => "is row")));
    else
        echo json_encode(array(array('value' => "no row")));
    return;*/

    $matches = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
        $matches[] = array('value' => $row["BinCode"], 'label' => $row["BinCode"].' - '.$row["ItemCode"],
            'name' => $row["ItemName"], 'whscode' => $row["WhsCode"], 'asOfDate' => $row["DataAsOfDate"]);
    }

    echo json_encode($matches);
}
?>
```

Note: My boss is having me use MySql and not MySqli extension for now.

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/NUaTy/, can you show `getWhsInfo` ?

Comment: Strange.. That method is for taking the selected value set in `txtBin` and making an ajax call to load a table on the page. It isn't relevant to the AC, but I can show it if you'd still like.

Comment: So, can you update it with this code ? How do you get the select value on the backend ?

Comment: What this line `$('#pulledData').html(result);` results ? Have you tried to debug your code with some `error_log`s ? Where did it stop ? How do you get `bin` in ajaxCalls.php ?

Comment: `bin` is user input. That part works fine, and like I said is irrelevant. I can enter a value and load my table via ajax fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you're doing something like the following.

`if(empty($_GET["bin"]))` or `if(!$_GET["bin"])` to check it's value.

But in this cases if `bin` is `0`, the first case results in `true` and the second in `false`.

So use `isset($_GET["bin"])` instead.

Comment: Ahh.. yes, it seems `!empty($_GET["term"])` on `'0'` is the issue. Thank you very much!